# Calling .net dll in java app which is going to run on linux box?

Tags: java, .net, linux

I am looking for open source option to call .net dll in java application which is going to be deployed & run over linux box. I searched over internet and found below option might be relevant (ignoring direct JNI option as it needs Visual C++ knowledge and my .net dll has very complex implementations):

a) JNA (Java Native Call)

b) JNI4NET

c) IKVM

Just an important mention, I can't make any modification in the .net source and regenerate .dll. I have to use it as is.

Any recommendations with briefing the limits & advantages of each option? Or if there is any other easy & robust open source framework available to use ? And do I need to mandatorily install emulator(s) like WINE or MONO over linux box to support .net dlls or there is a workaround ?

Comment: I dont think if it is possible at all!, using a dll in linux? dll is not considered native in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) .

It bridges the gap between mono and java to allow easy interoperability, e.g.:

```
import cli.System.IO.*;

public class ShowDir{

   public static void main(String[] args){
       String[] files = Directory.GetFiles("."); //.NET System.IO
       for(String file : files){
           System.out.println(file);
       }
   }
}
```